# SQL For each unique value in Column A, sum Column B. If sum is greater than 50, create Column C and add value "Y", else "N"

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, aggregation

Seems simple, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I have the table below.

```
ID        Total
1         20
1         30
1         30
2         10
2         10
```

For each unique value in 'ID' column, I want the sum of 'Total' column. If the sum of the total is greater than 50, create new column 'Result' and add value 'Y', if not then add value 'N'.

The result should look like this. Yes, I want to keep each row.

```
 ID        Total        Result
 1         20           Y
 1         30           Y
 1         30           Y
 2         10           N
 2         10           N
```

I'm stuck....

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, ???

Comment: Google Big Query

Answer (score 3):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(total) over (partition by id) >= 50 then 'Y' else 'N' end)
from t;
```

Comment: @Patrick . . . This is standard syntax and should work in any database.

Comment: So the sum total column is actually a derived column from a calculation of other columns. my code looks something like this based off above suggestion: 

CASE WHEN sum(ifnull(X - Y - Z,0)) over (Partition by ID) < 50 then 'Y' Else 'N' end as Result. 

I'm getting this error: Syntax error: Parenthesized expression cannot be parsed as an expression, struct constructor, or subquery at [94:4]

Comment: @Patrick . . . (1) You don't need `ifnull()`; `sum()` removes `NULL` values.  (2) are you sure you are using standard SQL?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed in my Google Big Query settings that it is Standard SQL